# getting syntax error when trying to run ren command

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to build my software using `cx_freeze` for which I built a bat file that runs the build command so when the build is completed it generates build directory inside which there is another directory `exe.win-amd64-3.6` containing the bundled code. inside which there is `lib/scipy/spatial/cKDTree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`  now this file has to be renamed as ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd for the build to run. I am trying to automate this by including rename in batch file but it's giving error.

I am trying to run rename command when build  is completed but it's not working i get the error the syntax is incorrect. i tried to remove

```
%~dp0
```

even this didn't work

```
@ECHO OFF
Set "FRAS_Folder=%~dp0build_logs\FRAS"
If Not Exist "%FRAS_Folder%" MD "%FRAS_Folder%"
Call :Gen_Report_Name fras_logname
echo FileName : "%fras_logname%"
echo Absolute PathName : "%FRAS_Folder%\%fras_logname%"
REM Example save the result of this command with a log file into this folder
python setup.py build>"%FRAS_Folder%\%fras_logname%"
@REM rename the scipy.spatial.cKDtree file to scipy.spatial.ckdtree in lib/scipy/spatial
@REM rename the file cKDTree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd to ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd in lib/scipy/spatial
ren "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\cKDTree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd" "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"


pause & exit /b

:::::::::::::::::: FUNCTION :::::::::::::::::::
:Gen_Report_Name <file_with_date to be set>
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set "stamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
Set "%1=%stamp%.log"
Exit /b
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly help me figure what's the issue!

Comment: Maybe you could add the exact error text to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for the **ren** command. See `ren /?`
The second filename must be a filename without path.
If you prefer to include the path for the second filename use the **move** command.

Answer (score -1):

Windows is case insensitive so the files are having the same name. You will need to use an intermediate filename to change the case of the filename.

Try this:

```
ren "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\cKDTree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"  "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.tmp"
ren "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.tmp"  "%~dp0build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
```